# Google map activity and navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, dictionary, navigation, drawer

I have my first activity splash activity. I want to implement google map in my application with navigation drawer so should I make two separate activities - google map and navigation drawer ? If I make separate activities then which should be called from splash activity ?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have an Activity with just a Navigation Drawer. Put them both in one Activity.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make two different activity, you can use fragment to implement google map and navigation drawer using single activity.